# How create dict from lists of list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have next list:

`l = [['a',1] ['b',2], [3], ['d',4]]`

And i need  to create key 'key1' for  element and for others  key will be the first and the value the next element

`{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'key1':3, 'd': 4}`

How can I do it?

Comment: Where does the 'key1' come from?

Comment: I need to create this key for this element and for the others the key will be the first and the value the next element

Comment: you need to mention what rule defines `key1`. What should be the key next time element with single list is found.

Comment: While the list is two long, create a dictionary d1={x[0]:x[1] for x in l}, then create a key for the next value and apply the first rule again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to name your keys as `key1`, `key2`.. and so on when a key is not found:

```py
l = [['a',1], ['b',2], [3], ['d',4]]

d = {}
i = 1
for x in l:
    try:
        d[x[0]] = x[1]
    except IndexError:
        d['key'+str(i)] = x[0]
        i += 1

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'key1': 3, 'd': 4}
```

Note, this solution assumes that list will always contain list having 1 or 2 elements only.

Comment: This could be improved by checking the length of x rather than using try/except